# How to use payment gateway in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an android application using phonegap and I want to make only 30% of my app to be free and the rest should be a paid one..I have learnt that there are some plugins called Inapbilling and Callbackbilling..Which one is the best to make it works??Can anybody please suggest me..??

Answer (score -1):

Here's the [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/PayPalPlugin) to PayPal Plugin. If it helps. 
I have used it in one of my projects earlier !